# SQLAlchemy: Transaction management

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

Here is the sample code

```
engine = create_engine(url="postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:0000@localhost:5432/db")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit = False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_database_session():
    try:
        session = SessionLocal()
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/api/v1/users")
def add_user(data: AppUserCreateModel, session: Session = Depends(get_database_session)):
    with session.begin():
        #db call 1
        session.commit()

        #db call 2 results in an error
        session.commit()
```

How can I structure it so that I can have multiple commits inside a transaction and if any commit result in an error, it should rollback all previous commits?

Comment: Nested transactions in Postgres is implemented through savepoints, so you'll have to explicitly use that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/subxacts.html - these are available in SQLAlchemy through `begin_nested`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint - see the examples of how to use a context manager to manage what gets added through a nested transaction.

Comment: can I ask why you want such a behavior? if you want all of them to be in the same transaction, why not commit at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You put the exception handling in your `get_database_session` function. Also, on the back of @python_user's comment, a 'transaction' should normally hold all the SQL queries with one commit at the end. If you need to insert a record and get a primary key value, you can use the `flush` method.

```
def get_database_session():
    try:
        session = SessionLocal()
        yield session
    except Exception as err:
        #Would be better to limit this to specific SQLAlchemy errors
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()


@app.post("/api/v1/users")
def add_user(data: AppUserCreateModel, session: Session = Depends(get_database_session)):
    with session.begin() as db_session:
        # run you first set of queries
        db_session.flush()

        # run you second set of queries
        db_session.commit()
```